# Django models - referencing more instances of another model

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-templates, django-views

hi have a model Invoice on which i have a subject_id field referencing a subject, and various fields which represents  activities. these are integer fields and represents the number of each activities for that invoice. What i want is to create a new model Activity, which contains fields like label, price for that activity. every Invoice instance could contain a different number of activity, and not a fixed number. How can i do that (maybe it's really simple but i can't figure out it now)?

any help?
thanks, Luke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    label = ...
    price = ...

class Invoice(models.Model):
    activities = models.ManyToManyField("Activity")
```

This assumes that a single activity can be shared between numerous invoices. If you want the situation where a single activity belongs to a single invoice, but an invoice can contain numerous activities:

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    label = ...
    price = ...
    invoice = models.ForeignKey("Invoice")

class Invoice(models.Model):
    ...
```

Comment: thanks, heard many times about many-to-many fields but were not clear to me, now it's a bit more clear. another question: if i have to add a  quantity (integer) to any activity contained an a single invoice, how can i do it (i mean it have to be a field of Invoice or of Activity? i think it's an Invoice field but don't know how to represent it). It's not so clear to me enough as you can see :-)